# Use Android on Arduino TFT

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, display, android, tft

I don't know whether this is possible or not but is there any way that I can run something similar to Android on a normal TFT. I want to make complex graphics but can't program those complex programs using the Adafruit TFT library.

Arduino Mega 2560 with Elegoo TFT 2.8"

Comment: a TFT is just a display ... it does not run code

Comment: start at the begining ... write a sketch that displays a full screen image on the TFT  ..

Comment: As jsotola says, start simple. Learn to draw lines and rectangles and such. Then learn how to combine those into the graphics that you want. The problem with "fancy" graphics is that they are generally big - based around bitmap images, which the Arduino can't handle well. You need some extra storage (flash chip, SD card, etc) to store them. Maybe learn how to display bitmap images from SD card would be a good step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not even remotely. Android runs on a powerful computer not a tiny embedded microcontroller.